# Getting all unique values and the count of their occurences from Flask SQLAlchemy table

Tags: pandas, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask app where users can tag their posts with keywords. These tags are separated by a space and are stored in the below model in the `tags` column.

```
class Post(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=False, nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    urls = db.Column(db.String(1000), unique=False, nullable=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    tags = db.Column(db.String(400), unique=False, nullable=True)
    upvotes = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, nullable=False, default=0)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post ('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"
```

I would like to get a table that I can publish to an html page that lists out all of the unique tags and the number of times they occur (sorted by occurrences, descending).

**Attempt**
So, in order to this, I figured I need to 1). get all the tags; 2). loop through them to split by the space (tag.split(' ')); 3). append them back to a dataframe; 4). loop through to count the occurrences.

This does not seem like a very efficient way to do it. But I have tried it nonetheless and this is what I have.

*Get all tags*

```
all_tags = Post.query.with_entities(Post.tags)
```

*Get all unique tags*

```
unique_tags = Post.query.with_entities(Post.tags).distinct()
```

*Get tag counts (does not work)*

```
counts = pd.Series(Post.query.with_entities(Post.tags)).value_counts()
```

but this counts the entire tag string, not the individual tags that are separated by ' '. I feel like this should be straightforward but I cant quite work it out. How can I do this?

Here is some dummy data to play with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3},
 'tags': {0: 'tag1 tag2',
  1: 'tag3 tag4',
  2: 'tag5 tag6 tag7',
  3: 'tag2 tag3 tag4 tag1'}})
```

Where the desired result is something like...

```
{'tag1': {0: 'tag2', 1: 'tag3', 2: 'tag4', 3: 'tag5', 4: 'tag6', 5: 'tag7'},
```

'2': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
pd.Series(df.tags.str.split(' ').sum()).value_counts()

Out[659]:
tag1    2
tag4    2
tag3    2
tag2    2
tag6    1
tag7    1
tag5    1
dtype: int64
```